# how to prevent crash in swift when using crash-prone code with no thrown errors

Tags: ios, swift, exception, error-handling, crash

Assume that I'm using some closed source framework that has some code that sometimes crashes. For example consider this:

```
public class A {
    public static func a() {
        let myNumber = Int("qqqqq")
        print(myNumber!)
    }
}
```

So `A` is a class in an closed sourced framework that I use. My question is this: if I have the code below, am I doomed to crash? Or is there any way to prevent app from crashing in any situation if you know almost where the crash does happen?

```
import ClosedSourceFramework

class my class {
    func myFunc() {
        A.a()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doomed in this case. You can't prevent a crash if the code you are calling is force-unwrapping a nil optional.

Comment: I'm not specific about force-unwrapping, a few days ago I was using firebase and I was getting a crash error because of using a sqlite file in several threads, I knew what line of code execution would crash my code, but I couldn't use do-try-catch for that. what am I asking is a way to wrap a portion of code in something and be sure that your code will not crash and you will catch any miss-behave

Comment: Not in Swift. Bad code will crash and you can't wrap it in anything to prevent it from crashing. `do/catch` is only for handling code that declares that it throws an error. That's very different from crashes caused by exceptions.

Comment: You can use 'Guard' or 'IF LET' statements for optional type casting values.

Comment: if you are really sure, take a look on Swizzling technics